# Reading a list of names and passing as argument to ncbi esearch program?

Tags: shell, command-line

Hi there I have this script and I would like to improve it to make it more automatized:

```
esearch -db assembly -query 'species[organism] AND latest[filter]' \
    | esummary \
    | xtract -pattern DocumentSummary -element FtpPath_GenBank \
    | while read -r line ; 
    do
        fname=$(echo $line | grep -o 'GCA_.*' | sed 's/$/_genomic.fna.gz/') ;
        wget "$line/$fname" ;
    done
```

So I works very fine and I always get what I need, but I have a big list of queries tha I need to pass to the script "- query 'name'.

There are a simple way to add the name arguments reading them from a txt?

I got this idea:

```
input="bact_taxa_3.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do
  mkdir $line
  cd $line
  esearch -db assembly -query $line'_bacterium AND latest[filter]' \
      | esummary \
      | xtract -pattern DocumentSummary -element FtpPath_GenBank \
      | while read -r line ; 
    do
        fname=$(echo $line | grep -o 'GCA_.*' | sed 's/$/_genomic.fna.gz/') ;
        wget "$line/$fname" ;
        cd ..
   done
done < "$input"
```

I act crazy because it saved one downloaded file in many different location and not in the new directory.

any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `got this idea:` Did it work? Looks like you are missing a `done`

Comment: Yaeh I was getting a error just because that...Thanks